# Dynamic "Columns:=Array(1,2,3)"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic

I am trying to make a dynamic "Remove Duplicates" macro, but have difficulties making the `Columns:=Array(1,2,3)` dynamic.

What I have is this:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Evaluate ("Row(1:"& numOfCol &")")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=MyArray, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: `MyArray = Application.Transpose(Evaluate ("Row(1:"& numOfCol &")"))`  The array must be one dimensional and the Evaluate is returning a 2d array.

Comment: Typo: `Columns:=MyArray`. Probably best to add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Duplicates

- The 'RemoveDuplicates' array needs to be declared as variant, needs to be zero-based and needs to be evaluated (`Evaluate()` or just `()`).
- `Evaluate("Row(1:" & numOfCol & ")")` will return a 2D one-column array. If you do an `Application.Transpose`, it will become a 1D array, but the problem is that it is one-based.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    
    Const NumOfCols As Long = 3
    
    Dim MyArray As Variant: ReDim MyArray(0 To NumOfCols - 1)
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To NumOfCols
        MyArray(n - 1) = n
    Next n
        
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(MyArray), Header:=xlYes
        
End Sub
```

Comment: The above works great! thanks. But is it possible to make " Const NumOfCols As Long = 3 " be based on a cell value? I would like the macro to be used, even if I change the number of columns I have.

Comment: @Kristian: Use `NumOfCols` as an argument: `Sub RemoveDupes(ByVal NumOfCols As Long)`, remove the `Const` line, and in another procedure use e.g. `RemoveDupes Range("G1").Value`.

Comment: Not sure how it should look like. Have tried diffrent things and can't get it to work.

Comment: Show me what you have tried. Add it to your post.

Comment: If you want to always apply this to all columns of the range, instead of the first line use `Dim NumOfCols As Long: NumOfCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`.